# Install Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Visual Studio(VS) 2015 on my desktop on Windows operating system. I thought when I opened the VS 2015, I expected to see the Xamarin in it, but it does not. Then I installed the Xamarin again, and again and again, but still Xamarin does not show up in VS 2015.

I wonder what is wrong? what am I missing? By the way, I still have Visual Studio 2013 on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

uninstall all the existing versions of visual studio ( 2010, 2012, 2013) except Visual Studio 2015 and then install Xamarin, and then you could able to see Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will useful for you.,

File - > New -> Project -> and Click Open Visual Studio Installer. Check this image

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXv7p.png)